# How can I know my php session information in dot net application?

Tags: php, asp.net, outlook-addin

I have developed a website in php-zend with SQL server 2008r2 in which we can create requests. I am building an add-in for Outlook in asp.net with C# to create a request directly from email also.

But at the time of request creation from Outlook, I want to know whether that person is already logged into the website or not. If not then he needs to log into the website first, then only he can create a request from Outlook.

So basically I want to synchronize my website and the Outlook add-in application. I searched for active directory also, but could not get any idea how to achieve that.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Mausami

Comment: Those are two completely separate systems on different machines with different authentication mechanisms. Why not have the user authenticate via the Outlook plugin separately? That would be easier. If you must, you'd have to get the Outlook plugin to use some API or authentication token system to check the web site for authentication, but by the time you do that, it would probably be just as much as doing full authentication in the Outlook plugin anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jon Adams. but how can i do user authentication of my website in outlook add-in ?

Comment: My website is in php and outlook add-in is in .NET. So In short, I just want that the user should log into the website to use the outlook plugin in outlook emails. But I don't know how to do?

Comment: There's no built-in auth mechanism for Outlook add-in to .Net site — you would have to code your own interface and communication with the web site auth mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really designed to do this. You would need to look up the phpsessid value in the cookie set for your website on the local computer.

That's basically impossible because,

- Every browser and OS store cookies differently, checking all the major browser cookie stores would be cumbersome and slow
- If the browser is open when you're add in runs, the cookies will probably have an exclusive lock on them
- Private browsing does not save cookie values to disk

Use authentication within you're plugin instead.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. will have to do authentication in plugin only.